# Displaying Locally stored images in response to JSON table population result

Tags: php, ios, json, swift

I am working on populating an iOS tableview (swift) with content from a json script with a php service. I have the content populating properly, but I am trying to show a local image icon depending on a characteristic of the table content.

I have tried two options:
 1. just assigning the image directly;

```
myCell.headlineLabel!.text = item.title
myCell.sourceLabel!.text = item.source
myCell.sourceIcon!.image = UIImage(named: "bbc.png")
```

2. assigning the content conditionally depending on the value of the incoming item.source

   if(item.source == "BBC Business"){
       myCell.sourceIcon!.image = UIImage(named: "bbc.png")
   }else if(item.source == "BBC Politics"){
       myCell.sourceIcon!.image = UIImage(named: "bbc.png")
   }else if(item.source == "CNN Money"){
       myCell.sourceIcon!.image = UIImage(named: "CNN Icon.png")
   }else if(item.source == "CNN Markets"){
       myCell.sourceIcon!.image = UIImage(named: "CNN Icon.png")
   }

I'm wondering if anyone has any experience with this, or whether it's even possible.

I would really appreciate any feedback!

Thanks, 
Alex :)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do that

```
switch item.source {
    case "BBC Business","BBC Politics":
    myCell.sourceIcon!.image = UIImage(named: "bbc")
    default:
    myCell.sourceIcon!.image = UIImage(named: "CNNIcon")
    //watch out with the space on UIImage name
}
```

The elegant way to do that is using a ENUM.

Comment: Hmm.. Makes sense. I will try this later :) Thanks!

Do my declarations of UIImage look okay? 

I'm finding that even when I just select one image and don't bother with cases I still don't get anything displaying.